# updating a very large oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have a very large table people with 60M rows indexed on id, wish to populate a field newid for every record based on a look up table id_conversion (1M rows) which contains id and newid, indexed on id.
when I run

```
update people p set p.newid=(select l.newid from id_conversion l where l.id=p.id)
```

it runs for an hour or so and then I get an archive error ora 00257.
Any suggestions for either running update in sections or better sql command?

Comment: You could try an `exists` query, but I think Oracle's optimizer is smart enough to use the same plan for that.Do you have an index on `id_conversion (id, newid)`?

Comment: I have index on id but not newid. Can't see why there is a benefit to indexing on newid. However you are the second person to suggest that, so I am getting worried!

Answer (score 3):

To avoid writing to Oracle's undo log if your `update` statement hits every single row of the table then you are likely better off running a `create table as select` query which will bypass all undo logs, which is likely the issue you're running into as it is logging the impact across 60 million rows. You can then drop the old table and rename the new table to that of the old table's name.

Something like:

```
create table new_people as
select l.newid,
       p.col2,
       p.col3,
       p.col4,
       p.col5
  from people p
  join id_conversion l
    on p.id = l.id;

drop table people;

-- rebuild any constraints and indexes
-- from old people table to new people table

alter table new_people rename to people;
```

For reference, read some of the tips here: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_efficient_update_sql_dml_tips.htm

If you are basically creating a new table and not just updating some of the rows of a table it will likely prove the faster method.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt you will be able to get this to run in seconds.  Your query, as written, needs to update all 60 million rows.

My first advice is to add an index on `id_conversion(id, newid)`, to make the subquery more efficient.  If that doesn't help, then doing the update in batches might be the best way to go.

I should add.  Because you are updating all the rows, it might be faster to take the following approach:

- Copy the data into a new table with the new values.
- Truncate the original table.
- Insert the new data into the old table.

Inserts are faster than updates.

Comment: It is already indexed on id, not sure I understand the benefit of indexing on newid?

Comment: @TonyWolff . . . The index is a covering index for the query, so the original data is not needed, only the index.  This improves performance.

Comment: this sounds important but I don't  understand can you go into a little more detail

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answers above, which probably will work better in this case, you should know the MERGE statement 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm
that is used for updating one table according to another table and is far faster then update according to a select statement