# Update multiple columns which has millions of records

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table with millions of record and I added two new columns

```
alter table hr.employees add (ind char(1Byte), remove Char(1 Byte)); commit;
```

I have another view `hr.department` which has more data than this and it has these two columns .

So if I write and update for these records it takes so long.

```
update hr.employees a 
set (ind, remove) =(select ind, remove 
                    from hr.department b 
                    where a.dept_id = b.dept_id ) ;
```

It's been an hour it still goes with the update. Can some one help in this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34898762/sql-update-large-table or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47327180/updating-a-big-table-in-oracle-without-drooping-the-base-table or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32668214/updating-a-very-large-oracle-table

Comment: Have you checked the execution plan? If column dept_id in hr.department isn't indexed, the query will take ages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your table has millions of rows, using an `UPDATE` will very likely take too much time.

I would rename the old table, create a new table with the new columns already filled, then add indexes, constraints, comments and gather statistics.

```
RENAME employees to employees_old;

CREATE TABLE employees AS
SELECT a.col1, a.col2, ... a.coln, b.ind, b.remove 
  FROM employees_old a
  LEFT JOIN department b
    ON a.dept_id = b.dept_id;
```

Comment: this has been the most successful solution i've seen over time - build a new table with the changes, then drop the existing and switch over

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way to handle this update will likely be the following:

1. Find a time when no one else will be critically using the system.
2. Make a backup.
3. If they don't already exist, copy DDL for creating all indexes/constraints on that table.
4. Drop all indexes/constraints on that table.
5. Update your two columns.
6. Recreate indexes/constraints (this may take some time, but usually orders of magnitude less than updating every row in a big table with multiple indexes).

As usual, Burleson Consulting is a good resource: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_efficient_update_sql_dml_tips.htm

Comment: Actually the Burleson sites are a rather erratic source of advice, with some useful stuff and some just plain wrong suggestions. The link you post is a case in point, with advice which is almost twenty years old (the reference to Oracle 9i is the giveaway).